# Query which tabulates on multiple different dates in given record

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that has single line entries for customers and events. For instance:

```
    custid   lead_created_date, signed_contract_date, completed_date 
      9999     01-01-1980         02-23-1980            03-15-1980
      2222     01-15-1980         01-18-1980            02-13-1980
```

Now I need to get a set of stats on in-period events. Essentially how many events happened each month. In the above case:

```
             Leads Created      Signed Contracts   Completed Projects
    01-1980       2                   1                    0
    02-1980       0                   1                    1
    03-1980       0                   0                    1
```

Now this is different from a cohorted view where I would simply take the lead dates and show you the cohorts. I actually need the in-period activity.  This is a simple view and I actually have a dozen or so stages.  So the code below works for two elements, however, when I simply nest a third run for the third set of dates I get a resources exceeded/too complex subqueries error from BigQuery.

There has to be a better way to accomplish this in a single view.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 

### Count SRA in period
WITH dates AS(
    SELECT format_datetime("%Y %B", day) as YEAR_MONTH
    FROM UNNEST(
        GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) as day
)
SELECT dates.YEAR_MONTH
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN dates.YEAR_MONTH = FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y %B",Lead_Created_Datetime) THEN 1 END) AS Leads_Created
FROM dates
JOIN `Main_Reporting_V` LEADS ON dates.YEAR_MONTH = FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y %B", LEADS.Lead_Created_Datetime)
GROUP BY dates.YEAR_MONTH) L

#### Count Opptys in period
JOIN (
WITH dates AS(
    SELECT format_datetime("%Y %B", day) as YEAR_MONTH
    FROM UNNEST(
        GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) as day
    
)
SELECT dates.YEAR_MONTH
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN dates.YEAR_MONTH = FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y %B",Opptys.Lead_Created_Datetime) THEN 1 END) AS Opptys_Created
FROM dates
JOIN `Main_Reporting_V` OPPTYS ON dates.YEAR_MONTH = FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y %B", Opptys.Oppty_Created_Datetime)
GROUP BY dates.YEAR_MONTH
) O
ON L.YEAR_MONTH = O.YEAR_MONTH
```

I believe you mean the following which still throws the flag of "too many subqueries or subqueries too complex"

```
  ### Count SRA IN period
WITH
  dates AS (SELECT format_datetime("%Y %B",day) AS YEAR_MONTH
  FROM UNNEST( GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS day ),
  
  LEADS AS (SELECT
    dates.YEAR_MONTH,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN dates.YEAR_MONTH = FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y %B",Lead_Created_Datetime) THEN 1
    END) AS Leads_Created
  FROM dates
  LEFT JOIN`CCA_Main_Reporting_V` LEADS
  ON dates.YEAR_MONTH = FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y %B", LEADS.Lead_Created_Datetime)
  GROUP BY dates.YEAR_MONTH)

### Count Opptys IN period 
 
,OPPTYS AS (SELECT
    dates.YEAR_MONTH,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN dates.YEAR_MONTH = FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y %B",Opptys.Lead_Created_Datetime) THEN 1
    END ) AS Opptys_Created
  FROM dates
  JOIN `CCA_Main_Reporting_V` OPPTYS
  ON dates.YEAR_MONTH = FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y %B", Opptys.Oppty_Created_Datetime)
  GROUP BY dates.YEAR_MONTH )
#
SELECT
  dates.YEAR_MONTH,
  Leads_Created,
  Opptys_Created
  
FROM
  dates 
  LEFT JOIN LEADS ON dates.YEAR_MONTH = LEADS.YEAR_MONTH
  LEFT JOIN OPPTYS on dates.YEAR_MONTH = OPPTYS.YEAR_MONTH
#LEFT JOIN
#  OPPTYS ON dates.YEAR_MONTH = LEADS.YEAR_MONTH
LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe simplifying a query could help. Try using a single GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY subquery and then LEFT JOINING other 3 subqueries (`select lead_created_date, count(*) from table group by lead_created_date`) to it.

UPDATE:
More like:

```
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT format_datetime("%Y %B", day) AS YEAR_MONTH
  FROM UNNEST( GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS day 
),
LEADS AS (
  SELECT
    dates.YEAR_MONTH,
    COUNT(*) AS Leads_Created
  FROM `CCA_Main_Reporting_V` LEADS
  GROUP BY dates.YEAR_MONTH
)
,OPPTYS AS (
  SELECT
    dates.YEAR_MONTH,
    COUNT(*) AS Opptys_Created
  FROM `CCA_Main_Reporting_V` OPPTYS
  GROUP BY dates.YEAR_MONTH 
)
SELECT
  dates.YEAR_MONTH,
  Leads_Created,
  Opptys_Created
FROM
  dates 
  LEFT JOIN LEADS ON dates.YEAR_MONTH = LEADS.YEAR_MONTH
  LEFT JOIN OPPTYS on dates.YEAR_MONTH = OPPTYS.YEAR_MONTH
#LEFT JOIN
#  OPPTYS ON dates.YEAR_MONTH = LEADS.YEAR_MONTH
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Tried this approach but still get the same flag. I've added the second set of code above. Suggestions?

Comment: Aa bit different, added details.

Answer (score 0):

After much soul searching, I realized that the underlying table was a view. My query wasn't too complicated but the view build is crazy convoluted (not my code).  Once I **saved the view as a table** then Sergey's answer works brilliantly!